# NodeJS server executes two times?

Tags: node.js

I tried to develop a basic HTTP server with follow code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

And works fine and page return:
Hello World

After that i tried to understand the infinite cycle in NodeJS server and discover that:
when use this code:

```
var http = require("http");
var n = 1;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    n++;
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    console.log('call: %d', n);
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

And works fine page return:
Hello World

But seeing the log i found a strange result, when page refresh.
call: 2
call: 3
Basically at every call (page refresh) the server executes two times, why? This is the number of threads that run at every call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `console.log(request.url);`. I'm betting that the browser is checking for `favicon.ico` also.

Comment: but why in every page refresh the console added two lines ? the correct not would one time at every refresh? i'm try in different browser and the answer is the same

Comment: Well, what does it output when you add `console.log(request.url);`?

Comment: when add this console.log(request.url); is: 
call: 2
/
call: 3
/favicon.ico

Comment: Yep, so there's nothing weird going on. You could just check the url for favicon requests and return with 404 or respond back with an actual favicon in that case if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var n = 1;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    if(request.url != '/favicon.ico')
    {
       n++;
       response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
       response.write("Hello World");
       console.log('call: %d', n);
       response.end();
    }
}).listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, dont execute 2 times. Executes only 1 time. If you execute console.log(request.url); you know this.